# Delete Files from Directory that are Older Than a Given Time

Tags: files, delete, date-and-time

I've been searching for this for several hours but couldn't find any solution. I have a folder (Call_Rec) which contain thousands of files and I want to delete only those files that are older than a given date. It seems like a basic feature or requirement but I'm unable to find any solution for it. How can I do so in Android? Is there any app or way to achieve this?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a regular file manager and choosing to sort the items on their modified date? I would recommend using Solid Explorer because I know with it you can long press a file, then scroll and long press another file and it automatically selects all files between the two selected files. That way you can choose from what date to what date you want to delete.

Another option is to plug your phone into a computer and use the computer to sort on date, then click the start file and shift click the end file to select all within a range.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll check solid explorer. I knew about sorting but selection of files or unselection of few hundreds out of thousands was an issue. I'll see if it could be overcome with the detection method you described about Solid Explorer. I wish there could be an app on which I could give a data range and it could filter the files based on that.

Comment: Thanks for help. My issue is resolved and I've deleted the required files by using Solid Explorer. But I still wish there could be an app or option in the file explorer app whoch could filter the files based on date range.